# Navigation Drawer Not working not able move to fragmets

Tags: navigation, fragment, navigation-drawer

I am working on an online shopping app. I used Navigation Drawer activity but it's simply not working for eg.

If I want to move to gallery fragment from home fragment it's not shifting (click is not working) and I'm not able to figure out have I deleted some important line or what is the problem.
Can anyone suggest something?

Here's what my **mainActivity** looks likes:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import com.example.chetnamartmobileapp.ui.home.HomeFragment;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final int HOME_FRAGMENT = 0;
    private static final int CART_FRAGMENT = 1;
    private static final int ORDER_FRAGMENT = 2;



    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private ImageView actionBarLogo;
    private static int currentFragment = -1;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        actionBarLogo = findViewById(R.id.actionbar_logo);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_framelayout);
        setFragment(new HomeFragment(), HOME_FRAGMENT);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        if (currentFragment == HOME_FRAGMENT) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.main_search_icon) {
            //todo: search
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.main_notification_icon) {
            //todo: notification
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.main_cart_icon) {
            //todo: cart
            gotoFragment("My Cart",new MyCartFragment(),CART_FRAGMENT);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void gotoFragment(String title, Fragment fragment, int fragmentNo) {
        actionBarLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        setFragment(fragment, fragmentNo);
        if (fragmentNo == CART_FRAGMENT) {
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setChecked(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_chetna_mart) {
            actionBarLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            setFragment(new HomeFragment(), HOME_FRAGMENT);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_orders) {
            gotoFragment("My Orders",new MyCartFragment(),ORDER_FRAGMENT);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_rewards) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_cart) {
            gotoFragment("My Cart",new MyCartFragment(),CART_FRAGMENT);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_wishlist) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_account) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sign_out) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment, int fragmentNo) {
        if (fragmentNo != currentFragment) {
            currentFragment = fragmentNo;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(frameLayout.getId(), fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest what can I do or change to enable it?

Comment: What does "simply not working" mean? What does it do? What do you expect it to do? And did you by any chance miss a language tag?

Comment: I am not  able to move to the other fragment for eg. if i am in home fragment and want to go to Gallery fragment or any other fragment i click to that option on the drawer its not shifting

Comment: I meant for you to edit it into your Question.